# how to show warning when upload image instead of jpeg format in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on image upload in Php. I am trying to upload only jpeg images. Here is my code

```
$pkg_img   = $_FILES['pkg_img']['name'];
$package_img = $ran.$pkg_img;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pkg_img']['tmp_name'],"../images/holiday-packages/" . $package_img);

$orgfile = "../images/holiday-packages/" . $package_img;
list($width,$height) = getimagesize($orgfile);
$newfile = imagecreatefromjpeg($orgfile);
$newwidth = $width*0.25;
$newheight = $height*0.25;
$thumb = "../images/holiday-packages/$ran1" . $package_img;
$new = $ran1.$package_img;
$truecolor = imagecreatetruecolor(640,320);
imagecopyresampled($truecolor,$newfile,0,0,0,0,640,320,$width,$height); 
imagejpeg($truecolor,$thumb,100);

unlink($orgfile);


$sql = "update holidays set pkg_img = '$new' where id = '$id'";
```

When i upload png or gif images i am getting these errors

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\justtravelservices\agent\upload-image.php on line 30
```

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): '../images/holiday-packages/46logo-NEW.png' is not a valid JPEG file in C:\xampp\htdocs\justtravelservices\agent\upload-image.php on line 30

Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\justtravelservices\agent\upload-image.php on line 36

What i need is when user select Png, Gif or any other format before upload to the server instead of jpeg, i want to show a warning message like "Please select only jpeg image." Please help me.

Comment: Have a read here http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php it shows about getting the file type (although it's not trustable for security purposes)

Comment: Parse the file name for file type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP array, output, output only where type = 'image/jpeg'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330788/php-array-output-output-only-where-type-image-jpeg)

Comment: I tried this. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I assume you've this kind of `HTML` form to upload only JPG/JPEG files then you can try like this way on the front end to restrict only JPG/JPEG file uploading using simple javascript,

```js
 var handleUpload = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('image_id');

// you can change this line if you want ONLY JPEG support
if (!fileInput.files[0].name.match(/.(jpg|jpeg)$/i)){
   console.log(fileInput.files[0].name);
    alert('Not a JPG/JPEG image format');
}else{
    alert('Image format is fine and it is either JPEG/JPG');
}
   
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    submit.addEventListener('click', handleUpload);

});
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="image" id="image_id" type="file" size="25" value="Select Image" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: @MahmoodMohammed glad it works for you. Best of luck :)